# How to best separate out an array?

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose I have an array such as the one below. If I wanted to separate and divide out the array below into multiple arrays containing records with only one tl_id, how would I go about doing this efficiently?

Example: so notice how there are two tl_id's (there could possibly be more): 275 and 328. I want two separate out that big array into two arrays. array1 would contain all the records that has tl_id's of 275. And array2 would contain all the records with tl_id 328.

I was thinking of a for loop and separating it out that way, but was hoping there's some PHP wizardy function I can use to simplify this action.

```
array(5) {
  [0] => array(14) {
    ["tl_id"] => int(275)
    ["tl_email"] => string(27) "abc@gmail.com"
    ["tl_first_name"] => string(9) "Jane"
    ["tl_last_name"] => string(6) "Doe"
    ["target_id"] => int(354)
    ["target_first_name"] => string(4) "Rudy"
    ["target_last_name"] => string(5) "Smith"
  }
  [1] => array(14) {
    ["tl_id"] => int(275)
    ["tl_email"] => string(27) "abc@gmail.com"
    ["tl_first_name"] => string(9) "Jane"
    ["tl_last_name"] => string(6) "Doe"
    ["target_id"] => int(354)
    ["target_first_name"] => string(4) "Rudy"
    ["target_last_name"] => string(5) "Smith"
  }
  [2] => array(14) {
    ["tl_id"] => int(275)
    ["tl_email"] => string(27) "abc@gmail.com"
    ["tl_first_name"] => string(9) "Jane"
    ["tl_last_name"] => string(6) "Doe"
    ["target_id"] => int(194)
    ["target_first_name"] => string(5) "Katie"
    ["target_last_name"] => string(4) "Smith"
  }
  [3] => array(14) {
    ["tl_id"] => int(328)
    ["tl_email"] => string(20) "qrf@hotmail.com"
    ["tl_first_name"] => string(6) "John"
    ["tl_last_name"] => string(9) "Smith"
    ["target_id"] => int(219)
    ["target_first_name"] => string(6) "Kelly"
    ["target_last_name"] => string(5) "Smith"
  }
  [4] => array(14) {
    ["tl_id"] => int(328)
    ["tl_email"] => string(20) "qrf@hotmail.com"
    ["tl_first_name"] => string(6) "John"
    ["tl_last_name"] => string(9) "Smith"
    ["target_id"] => int(213)
    ["target_first_name"] => string(5) "Chris"
    ["target_last_name"] => string(5) "Jones"
  }
}
```

Comment: array_filter would have been great, (With a code view I mean) but inefficient since you would have to iterate 2 times on the big array… Here is the doc though http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-filter.php

Comment: Not neccessarily, 2n iterations is ok. 2n = O(n)

Comment: yes but a foreach works with only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will be of help.

```
<?php
$test = array(
  array(
    "tl_id" => 275,
    "tl_email" => "abc@gmail.com",
    "tl_first_name" => "Jane",
    "tl_last_name" => "Doe",
    "target_id" => 354,
    "target_first_name" => "Rudy",
    "target_last_name" => "Smith",
  ),
  array(
    "tl_id" => 275,
    "tl_email" => "abc@gmail.com",
    "tl_first_name" => "Jane",
    "tl_last_name" => "Doe",
    "target_id" => 354,
    "target_first_name" => "Rudy",
    "target_last_name" => "Smith",
  ),
  array(
    "tl_id" => 278,
    "tl_email" => "abc@gmail.com",
    "tl_first_name" => "Jane",
    "tl_last_name" => "Doe",
    "target_id" => 354,
    "target_first_name" => "Rudy",
    "target_last_name" => "Smith",
  ),
);

$result = array_reduce($test,
    function($result, $item)
    {
        $result[$item["tl_id"]][] = $item;
        return $result;
    }
);
print_r($result);
```

This function walks the array and builds a new array where the items have been grouped by id.

Comment: legit yo. I came up with a similar solution, not using array_reduce tho.

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not have anything native that will *pluck* out certain elements of an array. There are many *Set* libraries available or part of frameworks that offer this functionality if you *really* don't want to use a `for` loop.

Nonetheless, there are a many [PHP Array Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php). You may be able to string a few together to achieve what you want. But, IMO, a `for` loop is going to be the most straighforward.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much the size if this main array may change, it could be quite difficult to separate it out into separate arrays. That's because you're going to need a different variable for each individual array. So, if the size of the main array can change, then you aren't going to know how many different variables you need.

May I ask why you need to split this main array into multiple arrays? There may be a better solution to your problem then doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$collection = array();
foreach($array as $value) {
        $collection[$value['tl_id']][] = $value; //It's a bad practice, but you 
                                                 //don't need to define the array 
                                                 //before pushing values to it
}
```

PHP doesn't have any special data parsing libraries that you were hoping for (at least, not for this specific situation). A `foreach` will probably be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
foreach($tls as $tl){
    $arrayName = "tl_{$tl['tl_id']}";
    ${$arrayName}[] = $tl;
}
```